# Phpstorm неверно читает пути

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

[image]

```
Здесь прописаны рабочие пути, но phpStorm не видит их, тем не менее они работают
```

[image]

```
Почему не работает так?:
<pre>
    ../../public/scripts.js
    ../../public/bootstrap.min.css
    ../../public/background.css
</pre>

хотя phpStorm в таком расположение путей начинает видеть файлы и их содержимое, но при этом этот вариант не работает, и я не могу использовать содержимое подключенных документов.

Файл в котором я всё это подключаю называется index.blade.php который находится public/resources/views
значит правильнее было бы подключать файлы из public используя путь ../../public а в итоге всё наоборот, и правильным оказывается public/../../ почему так?
```

Comment: 1) у вас public не установлен как resource root. ткните правой кнопочкой . mark directory

Comment: 2) пути строятся не от текущего файла, а от самого первого запущенного файла. Это index в корневой директории сайта

Comment: изменил на public/scripts.js  всё равно не работает. Папку public сделал общедоступной

Comment: вы resorce root указали?

Comment: да, папка public стала фиолетовой после этого действия

Comment: Вроде получилось. Изменил на просто scripts.js и стили соответственно background.css и bootstrap.css. Спасибо, основная проблема была в том что public была без resource root